# Consulta para contar distintos (MSSQL Server 2005 Express)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito número de oficios distintos de cada departamento:

Hice la siguiente consulta, pero no es lo que pide el enunciado:

```
SELECT depto_no, count(*)
FROM empleado
GROUP BY depto_no
```

El tema es que ya probé en poner `DISTINCT` en el `SELECT`, también probé con poner una subconsulta en el `FROM` (no sé si esté bien hacerlo así).

El resultado debe ser lo siguiente:

```
depto_no    valor
10          1
20          1
30          2 (los dos oficios distintos)
40          1
```

Comment: intentastes un disctinct con un Group by?, creo que un count(tu_id) con un group by tu_id deberia funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Necesito número de oficios distintos de cada departamento

Hay que poner el `DISTINCT` dentro del `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT depto_no, count(DISTINCT oficio) 
  FROM empleado 
 GROUP BY depto_no
```

Comment: Gracias sstan, con el DISTINCT dentro del count funciona perfecto!